# Obj-C Blocks Subclass Parameter

Tags: objective-c

I would like to subclass the parameter object of my block. In this case, I know it will always return the `NSObjectSubclass` type, so I don't want to cast it inside the block. This isn't working, it's saying I need to pass in an NSObject.

```
- (void)mainMethod {
    [self doStuff:^(NSObjectSubclass *sub) {
          // ERROR! Incompatible block pointer type
    }];
}

- (void)doStuff:(void (^)(NSObject *))onComplete {}
```

This error makes sense to me, but I could have sword you used to be able to do this, was this changed at some point? Is there any way to get around this error?

Comment: Declare it as `__kindof NSObject *` in the block parameter

Comment: @dan this seems to work! great!

Comment: @dan This looks like the correct answer, if you want credit go ahead and post it as an answer and I'll accept it, otherwise I'll answer it myself